# How to generate KML file with colored markers

Tags: google-maps, kml, geopandas

Having a geopandas dataframe with points with different properties, I would like to generate a KML file with markers with different colors depending on parameter value.

First, I tried to export the dataframe with simple command:

```
gdf.to_file(f'elevation_cluster.kml', driver='KML')
```

As I didn't find the way to directly export geopandas dataframe with colored markers, I tried the following:

```
from simplekml import Kml

colormap = ['37AB65', '3DF735', 'AD6D70', 'EC2504', '8C0B90']
vals = list(df_mo_110['value'])
longitudes = list(df_mo_110['geometry'].x)
latitudes = list(df_mo_110['geometry'].y)
colors = list(df_mo_110['k5cls'].apply(lambda x: colormap[x]))
kml = Kml()
fol = kml.newfolder()
for _, row in df_mo_110.iterrows():
    longitude = row.geometry.x
    latitude = row.geometry.y
    val = row.value
    color = colormap[row.k5cls]
    pnt = fol.newpoint(name=val, coords = [(longitude, latitude)])
    pnt.style.iconstyle.color = color
kml.save('test_kml.kml')
```

When I import the kml file to google maps, it seems that the colors haven't been taken into account as all the markers are colored with the same (default) color

The output looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
    <Document id="1">
        <Folder id="2">
            <Style id="5">
                <IconStyle id="6">
                    <color>37AB65</color>
                    <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                    <scale>1</scale>
                    <heading>0</heading>
                    <Icon id="7">
                        <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
                    </Icon>
                </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <Style id="10">
                <IconStyle id="11">
                    <color>AD6D70</color>
                    <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                    <scale>1</scale>
                    <heading>0</heading>
                    <Icon id="12">
                        <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
                    </Icon>
                </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <Style id="15">
                <IconStyle id="16">
                    <color>EC2504</color>
                    <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                    <scale>1</scale>
                    <heading>0</heading>
                    <Icon id="17">
                        <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
                    </Icon>
                </IconStyle>
            </Style>
            <Style id="20">
                <IconStyle id="21">
                    <color>8C0B90</color>
                    <colorMode>normal</colorMode>
                    <scale>1</scale>
                    <heading>0</heading>
                    <Icon id="22">
                        <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
                    </Icon>
                </IconStyle>
            </Style>
...
<Placemark id="4">
                <name>77.9385518904762</name>
                <styleUrl>#5</styleUrl>
                <Point id="3">
                    <coordinates>20.194198360555102,45.30681051976343,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark id="9">
                <name>77.3221460340015</name>
                <styleUrl>#10</styleUrl>
                <Point id="8">
                    <coordinates>20.195525984640607,45.30630142056596,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
            <Placemark id="14">
                <name>78.0660057592034</name>
                <styleUrl>#15</styleUrl>
                <Point id="13">
                    <coordinates>20.1985008143972,45.30460932455468,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
...
```

Does anyone know how to colorize the markers?

Comment: Can you share your output KML, or a sample?  Hard to debug without seeing what's actually ending up in the KML.

Answer (score 1):

Color component in KML has 4-components. IconStyle color should be length 8 not 6.

```
The order of color value is aabbggrr, where aa=alpha (00 to ff);
bb=blue (00 to ff); gg=green (00 to ff); rr=red (00 to ff).

For example, if you want to apply a blue color with 50 percent opacity
to an overlay, you would specify the following: <color>7fff0000</color>,
where alpha=0x7f, blue=0xff, green=0x00, and red=0x00.
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#iconstyle

Add "ff" to each of the colors to make them fully opaque.

```
<Style id="15">
    <IconStyle>
        <color>ffEC2504</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
        <heading>0</heading>
        <Icon id="17">
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
        </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

Change colormap to

```
colormap = ['ff37AB65', 'ff3DF735', 'ffAD6D70', 'ffEC2504', 'ff8C0B90']
```

If, however, the original colors are in RGB order then must reverse the color RGB values:

```
colormap = ['ff65AB37', 'ff35F73D', 'ff706DAD', 'ff0425EC', 'ff900B8C']
```